# Confusion in derivation of Formula of divergence

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

[image]
This is from the book Mathematical Methods (Arfken),
Can someone explain how did one del(x) and one dx came here,?

Comment: what is del(x)? Anyway, its just standard formula $f(x+\Delta,y,z)-f(x,y,z)\approx \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta $, or are you confused about something else?

Comment: You mean on the RHS of the highlighted equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the LHS of the highlighted equation represents is the change in $\rho v_x \,dy \,dz$ between two $x$ values. Let the rate of change of this wrt $x$ be $$\frac{\partial (\rho v_x \,dy\, dz)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (\rho v_x )}{\partial x} dy\,dz$$

Now $\Delta (\rho v_x)=\frac{\partial \rho v_x}{\partial x} \Delta x$. $\Delta x= x+dx/2-(x-dx/2)=dx$, So the RHS becomes,

$$\Delta (\rho v_x)=\frac{\partial (\rho v_x )}{\partial x}\,dy \,dz \,dx$$

This is a general technique while building differential equations. We calculate the variation of some quantity as a finite difference over a differential element. Then linking that change to the derivative or higher order terms gives a locally valid, differential equation for that quantity.